# MySql Limit rows but without truncating group of rows

Tags: mysql

I have the following table

```
id| name     |price| groupid | category
---------------------------------------
1 | product1 | 14  | grp1    | apparel
2 | product1 | 16  | grp1    | apparel
3 | product1 | 36  | grp1    | apparel
4 | product2 | 97  | grp2    | apparel
5 | product2 | 87  | grp2    | apparel
6 | product2 | 77  | grp2    | apparel
7 | product3 | 3   | grp3    | apparel
8 | product3 | 2   | grp3    | apparel
9 | product3 | 5   | grp3    | apparel
```

I want to fetch products in this table by category and group them by group id in app layer. This is the simple SELECT query I am using:

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE category = 'apparel'
LIMIT 0,5
```

The problem now is the query truncates the result and the last item in grp2 (id=6) is not returned (as one would expect).

I want a query the detects that one item of a group is not returned, fetching that item as well and then truncates the remainder of the result. Basically I want to return all items of a group or no items in a group at all.

How can i possibly achieve this ?

EDIT: each group can potentially have anywhere between 1 to 12 items. It is variable.

Comment: Just remove "LIMIT 0,5". It will return all or none record.

Comment: @ankur140290 removing won't do. I still need to limit the results and not get potentially thousands of results. I need LIMIT but not in a way the removes rows from a group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM products AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT groupid
   FROM (
      SELECT groupid 
      FROM products
      WHERE category = 'apparel'
      LIMIT 0,5) AS t
) AS t2 ON t1.groupid = t2.groupid
```

The query uses a derived table that contains all *distinct* `groupid` values that belong to the rows returned when `LIMIT` is applied.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/ITR51131)

Comment: This is fantastic, I will test this and then accept your answer. Thank you @Giorgos

Comment: How performant is this query ? Will it scale well if table is indexed properly ?